# Bootstrap : dropdown toggle doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use boostrap javascript api to toggle a dropdown menu.

[My Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dams_666/hFFR8/3/)

```
$('#login-panel2').dropdown('toggle');
```

After clicking, the menu is shown, but disappear instantly.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: its working in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to solve this problem is by setting the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) in CSS:

```
.nav {
     z-index: 1000
}
```

Or fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hFFR8/4/